# How to return a function pointer from CPython to Python then call a C function with ctypes?

Tags: python, function, pointers, casting, ctypes

I have CPython function:

```
void my_cfunc(int arg)
{
  printf("Hello from C; arg=%d\n", arg);
}

PyObject *get_fptr(PyObject * /*self*/, PyObject * /*args*/)
{
    return PyCObject_FromVoidPtr(my_cfunc, NULL);
}
```

Then later, in Python I have:

```
import mymodule

ptr = mymodule.get_fptr() # will return a PyCObject wrapping the C function pointer
```

Then later:

```
from ctypes import *

SOMEFUNC_T = CFUNCTYPE(c_void, c_int)
somefunc = SOMEFUNC_T(ptr) # <-- bad!
```

Now, if I change get_fptr to return as: PyLong_FromSize_t(size_t(my_cfunc)) then 'somefunc' will be valid.

But I don't want to cast a function pointer to a size_t.

Please advise

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I don't understand why you'd want to return a C function pointer from a Python extension only to call it from Python (via ctypes), while the logical thing would be to call the C function via the Python extension (unless I'm missing something).

Second, it does not look like ctypes supports PyCObject at all. Your call to CFUNCTYPE(None, c_int) [I replaced c_void with None] with a PyCObject argument fails because CFUNCTYPE expects an integer, and does not know what to do with a PyCObject.

Why not write a Python wrapper to my_cfunc instead, which you'll call from Python without the ctypes hassle? For example:

```
PyObject *call_fptr(PyObject *self, PyObject *args)
{
    int arg;
    if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "i", &arg))
        return NULL;

    my_cfunc(arg);
    Py_RETURN_NONE;
}
```

As a bonus, if ctypes is your thing, the Python wrapper to my_func can be used to instantiate a ctypes foreign function (unlike the PyCObject)!

```
from ctypes import *
import foo

SOMEFUNC_T = CFUNCTYPE(None, c_int)
cfunc = SOMEFUNC_T(foo.call_fptr)
cfunc(1)
```

**Edit:**
Specifying that the C function should take a variable number of arguments makes your question more difficult... How would you wrap your variable argument C function with ctypes anyway, considering that CFUNCTYPE requires a known set of arguments?

The problem in this case really boils down to converting a Python tuple to a variable argument list in C, which is apparently anything but trivial. In fact SWIG has dedicated a [section of its documentation](http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Varargs.html) to this problem, saying for instance this: *Most other wrapper generation tools have wisely chosen to avoid this issue*.

It does give the advise, though, that one can dynamically construct variable argument lists in a portable manner with the help of [libffi](http://sources.redhat.com/libffi/).

My suggestion, ultimately, is to wrap your variable arguments function with [SWIG](http://www.swig.org) and save yourself the pain.

Comment: Ok, I should have been precise. Actually void my_cfunc(int arg) should be something like: "void my_cfunc(int n1, ...)" ....

So, I have two solutions: (1) what I am doing (2) I have no idea how to wrap a va_arg function in Python. This is why I resort to return its function pointer and later calling it again w/ ctypes

Comment: No, with ctypes you can easily wrap a va_arg function :)

- Just get its address to ctypes (like my example shows).
- Call it with unlimited args, say cfunc(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6) ...
- Even nicer, you can call it as: cfunc(*args)

This is why I wanted to get the C function pointer and give it to Python then give it to ctypes and then I can call a va_arg function.

Comment: On a practical side, I want to mention that I wrapped a vaarg function nicely and it works...all I wanted is to avoid casting the function pointer to a size_t while giving it to ctypes. But now that seems to work and should continue working since size_t will have the same size as a pointer.

Comment: @Elias Bachalaany: so it is possible to instantiate CFUNCTYPE with variable argunents? The ctypes documentation hinted it wasn't feasible, wrt. printf/scanf. Anyway, now you know why you must cast to an integer :)